# In a multi-tenant solution which uses IdentityServer, where should knowledge of multi-tenancy live?

Tags: oauth-2.0, multi-tenant, identityserver3

I'm actively learning Identity Server and currently working on a new multi-tenant project with IdentityServer3. I'm being put on the project early after only a few weeks of development, and being tasked with fine-tuning the back-end architecture. Based on my research and how the project is currently laid out, I'm not sure it's correct.

Right now, there are two main projects, an IdentityServer3 project and an application project. Sounds good so far.

However, the Tenants and Groups do not live in the Identity project, they are currently living in the Application project, and the application project is soley aware of tenants and effectively delegating some of the "Auth" work that the Identity Server should be doing (as I see it).  What's more, is the Application project also has it's own entity and store for Users, and there is logic to keep the user stores between the Identity project and Application project in sync. When the application wants to show the profile pic or the email, it retrieves it from the local user store, which is hopefully up-to-date with the Identity project user store.

This is where things seemed off track to me. If we are to treat IdentityServer as a true "Auth as a Service", shouldn't identity information live in the Identity project, and that would include the multi-tenancy pieces? And instead of depending directly on User entities, the Application should instead only know about tokens & claims, retrieving user meta data that way (like the profile scope for email, profile pic, etc.), meaning there should be no need to keep two user stores "in sync" between projects.

My instinct is to move all of the user/multitenancy entities over to the Identity Server, and refactor the applications to depend on the tokens/claims instead of directly using the User or Tenant entity. Then introduce some new scopes to expose what little tenancy meta data we chose to expose to the client applications. I feel this is a more "security first" design and may separate concerns appropriately, however I'm new to Identity Server and not sure if I'm on the right track.

Could anyone here let me know if I'm thinking sane here, or maybe have the wrong idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thats how I would do it! Definitely on the right track

Comment: Yes what you are thinking is sane. Though in certain cases it's reasonable to have a (read-only) copy of some auth tables (like users) in application store, mostly for perfomance reasons or if you need to join to that Users table in your application for whatever reason. But if possible that should be avoided.

Comment: Great, thanks for the sanity check everyone! I feel more confident in the direction I'm thinking of taking it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You probably would need to keep a user "stub" in your application. This would be for linking to other entities, eg audit trails, things the user did, things they own, etc. This would mean your application would not have to keep hitting the id server to show user data, eg names, when users are using the system. How much data & how you keep it in sync will depend on your system.

Comment: Based on my experience, I will suggest the following, you have the same db for both the app and Auth. Your application is going to need more information about the tenant and user than that of the Auth. The auth does Care only about the validation of user, tenancy profiles and license check if required in the Auth. Mostly they will be used from your application. Hence, I contradict your approach. The responsibility of the auth is not to take care of the multi-tenancy. HTH

Comment: And what if we add another application later which also needs to know about tenancy? And now I have a application that is tightly-coupled to my identity server which nows about it's own application stuff, but is also responsible for delegating identity server auth to a new application which might have nothing to do with the first application? 

Seems like it'd be better to separate these dependencies.